# How can I transfer my SMS messages from an iPhone to a computer?

Tags: iphone, sms, transfer

I'm having a problem with my iPhone where it is simply not receiving any new SMS messages. All the messages on the phone are important so I don't want to delete them; I'd like to back up all the messages onto my computer (or transfer them to another iPhone) so they are safe.

Any suggestions on how to transfer SMS messages from the iPhone to my computer?

Comment: You can try creating a backup, then reset your phone and restore it from backup. This might help with the receiving SMS issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PhoneView](http://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/).

---

If you don't want to pay for the privilege, you can use [this hint](http://osxdaily.com/2010/07/08/read-iphone-sms-backup/).

iPhone backups created by iTunes contain the SMS database. It's located in a file named `3d0d7e5fb2ce288813306e4d4636395e047a3d28` in a sub-folder of `~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup/`. You can use a SQLite Database Viewer to view and export the SMS messages in that file.

If you're using Windows, the path to the backup files changes, but not the principle. Scroll down a bit to learn the Windows iPhone backup paths.